# MVC3 load controller in a View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, controller

I am trying to load a page and in that view i want to load another view from a different controller which retrieves information.
I can use:
 @Html.Partial("otherView")
which works for pages which require no data but i would like the page to retrieve data, so using :
@Html.Action("otherView") 
i thought should work but does not and i get an HttpException

"Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'."

There must be a way of doing this,

Thanks
Kelv

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 @Html.Action("otherView", "otherController", new { vm = viewModel })
```

and in the controller create an action

```
public ActionResult otherView(otherViewModel vm)
{
    return PartialView("otherView", vm);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for RenderAction.

[Here's the first article I found on the subject.](http://www.arrangeactassert.com/when-to-use-html-renderpartial-and-html-renderaction-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-views/)

Comment: Action or RenderAction is more or less the same. the only difference is the whether the result is rendered in the Response, or is returned as a string.
take a look at this : [Html.RenderAction and Html.Action](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx)